# Missing actionerror, however still works. How?

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2, error-handling

In Struts 2, in JSP file, I didn't use

`<s:actionerror />`

However, it is possible to display actionerror messages.

How is it possible?

Is this tag ( `<s:actionerror />`) not required to mention in jsp file?

Comment: Some themes add `<s:fielderror />` tags for you. See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your action class with `ActionSupport` and use `actionErrors` property.

```
<s:iterator value="actionErrors">
 <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: without doing all these, action error messages are already displayed. my question is how action error messages are displayed in the absence of actionerror(s) tag?

Comment: this property contains error messages. If I remove it, it won't display either `s:actionerror` or any other way including this.

Comment: If you have some errors displayed this may be not action errors but javascript, html5 errors, etc.

Comment: Please refer this example
http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/07/struts2-validation-with-example.html

in the employee.jsp, he is not using `<s:actionerror />`
however, error messages are still displayed. i am wondering, how it works!

Comment: This is a [client-side validation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/client-validation.html) and javascript is required there.

Comment: Am I correct to say that in the absense of validation.xml, we have to use `<s:actionerror />` to show validators error messages?

Comment: `s:actionerror` is used for server-side validation either declarative via `validation.xml` or programmatic, if you remove first you still can use the second option.